# String comparisons. How can you compare string with std::wstring? WRT strcmp

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to compare two formats that I expected would be somewhat compatible, since they are both generally strings.  I have tried to perform strcmp with a string and std::wstring, and as I'm sure C++ gurus know, this will simply not compile.  Is it possible to compare these two types?  Is there an easy conversion here?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to compare two wide strings or are you trying to compare a wide string to a normal string?

Comment: i have a char[256] coming in from a filestream that's marshalled from another program.  i then have to compare that (it represents a filename) to a std::wstring filename that is passed as a parameter to the function.  however, i can't logically compare these

Comment: Do you have any guarantees regarding encoding of those chars? Is it system locale encoding? Some specific known encoding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to convert your `char*` string - "multibyte" in ISO C parlance - to a `wchar_t*` string - "wide character" in ISO C parlance. The standard function that does that is called [`mbstowcs`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mbstowcs.3.html) ("Multi-Byte String To Wide Character String")

**NOTE**: as Steve pointed out in comments, this is a C99 function and thus is not ISO C++ conformant, but may be supported by C++ implementations as an extension. MSVC and g++ both support it.

It is used thus:

```
const char* input = ...;

std::size_t output_size = std::mbstowcs(NULL, input, 0); // get length
std::vector<wchar_t> output_buffer(output_size);

// output_size is guaranteed to be >0 because of \0 at end
std::mbstowcs(&output_buffer[0], input, output_size);

std::wstring output(&output_buffer[0]);
```

Once you have two `wstring`s, just compare as usual. Note that this will use the current system locale for conversion (i.e. on Windows this will be the current "ANSI" codepage) - normally this is just what you want, but occasionally you'll need to deal with a specific encoding, in which case the above won't do, and you'll need to use something like `iconv`.

**EDIT**

All other answers seem to go for direct codepoint translation (i.e. the equivalent of `(wchar_t)c` for every `char c` in the string). This may not work for all locales, but it will work if e.g. your `char` are all ASCII or Latin-1, and your `wchar_t` are Unicode. If you're sure that's what you really want, the fastest way is actually to avoid conversion altogether, and to use `std::lexicographical_compare`:

```
#include <algorithm>

const char* s = ...;
std::wstring ws = ...;

const char* s_end = s + strlen(s);

bool is_ws_less_than_s = std::lexicographical_compare(ws.begin, ws.end(),
                                                      s, s_end());
bool is_s_less_than_ws = std::lexicographical_compare(s, s_end(),
                                                      ws.begin(), ws.end());
bool is_s_equal_to_ws = !is_ws_less_than_s && !is_s_less_than_ws;
```

If you specifically need to test for equality, use `std::equal` with a length check:

```
#include <algorithm>

const char* s = ...;
std::wstring ws = ...;

std::size_t s_len = strlen(s);
bool are_equal =
    ws.length() == s_len &&
    std::equal(ws.begin(), ws.end(), s);
```

Comment: Is this C++? It seems to be C99, and I'm not sure what versions of the C library were merged into the C++ standard. Upvoted anyway - should work in practice either way.

Comment: Yeah, `mbstowcs` is C99, though in practice both C++ implementations I'm familiar with - MSVC and g++ - support this function.

Comment: It seems that the 100% portable ISO C++ approach would be to use the `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` facet and its `in()` method, but it is just so messy and verbose... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xse90h58.aspx - documentation for it in case anyone wants to try to write up a detailed answer for that.

Comment: @Pavel - if it wasn't messy and verbose, who would recognise it as a genuine C++ standard library thing?

Comment: WARNING: `mbstowcs()` does not count the final NUL character in the returned count! You should add 1 to `output_size` then.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your wstring to a string.

```
wstring a = L"foobar";
string  b(a.begin(),a.end());
```

Now you can compare it to any char* using b.c_str() or whatever you like.

```
char c[] = "foobar";
cout<<strcmp(b.c_str(),c)<<endl;
```

Comment: Sorry about the previous answer, I've changed it.

Comment: It's likely better to go other way (i.e. `char*` -> `wstring`), since there's less chance to lose data - you can use raw pointers into string as iterators. But otherwise the method is the same, and using constructors is better than other answer that uses `copy`. Caveat is the same: this may not work correctly for all locales.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to ask yourself why you are using std::wstring which is a unicode format with char* (cstring) which is ansi.  It is best practice to use unicode because it allows your application to be internationalized, but using a mix doesn't make much sense in most cases.  If you want your cstrings to be unicode use [wchar_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684497(EXCHG.10).aspx).  If you want your STL strings to be ansi use std::string.

Now back to your question.

The first thing you want to do is convert one of them to match the other datatype.

`std::string` an `std::wstring` have the [c_str](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/c_str) function

here are the function definitions

```
const char* std::string::c_str() const
const wchar_t* std::wstring::c_str() const
```

I don't remember off hand how to convert char * to wchar_t * and vice versa, but after you do that you can use strcmp.  If you google you'll find a way.

You could use the functions below to convert std::wstring to std::string then c_str will give you char * which you can strcmp

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// Prototype for conversion functions
std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string& s);
std::string WStringToString(const std::wstring& s);

std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string& s)
{
std::wstring temp(s.length(),L' ');
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
return temp; 
}


std::string WStringToString(const std::wstring& s)
{
std::string temp(s.length(), ' ');
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
return temp; 
}
```

Comment: This will only work if multibyte and widechar encodings for a given locale are "compatible" - e.g. if multibyte is really just ASCII or Latin-1, and widechar is Unicode. This won't work if multibyte is e.g. CP1251.

Comment: This is why I like stackoverflow.  If you go to some random google result you might get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way is

```
if( std::wstring(your_char_ptr_string) == your_wstring)
```

I say dirty because it will create a temporary string and copy your_char into it. However, it will work just fine as long as you are not in a tight loop.

Note that wstring uses 16 bit characters (i.e unicode - 65536 possible characters) whereas char* tends to be 8 bit characters (Ascii, Latin english only). They are not the same, so wstring-->char* might loose accuracy.

-Tom

Comment: This looks better than my idea - for some reason, I thought std::wstring wouldn't have the right conversions. My approach creates two extra objects - one named (and probably heavier than a simple wstring), the other a temporary wstring instance.

Comment: `std::wstring` does not have any constructor from `const char*`.

Comment: You can build a wstring from char* the underlying types are different. wstring uses wchar_t (which may be 32 bytes not just 16 on some systems).

Comment: You can build it, but nonetheless code as given will not even compile.

Comment: Yup, would need to be `std::wstring(pcYourString, pcYourString+strlen(pcYourString))` to compile. Ugly, but works IFF `wchar_t` is Unicode/UTF16/UTF32 and `char*` is ASCII or ISO8859-1. It won't work for the rather popular ISO-8859-15 (the €-variant of ISO-8859)