# C++: How to check if a determined process is running

Tags: c++, windows

**EDIT2: For those who think this is a duplicate, no this isn't. This was made in different context, knowing if a proccess is running and i did not knew i needed to convert till here 'martin' gives me the answer :p**

**EDIT: Answer was found!** https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637971/4908011

I'm using Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2013 Deluxe. I can't seem to find any way to make a compatible x32 console application finding a process.

I need to know if a process is running, e.g. `RobloxPlayerBeta.exe`.

I keep getting the error:

> WCHAR* incompatible with const char*

At 'strcmp(procEntry.szExeFile, name)'

The code I use:

```
bool ProcessRunning(const char* name)
{
HANDLE SnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

if (SnapShot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return false;

PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

if (!Process32First(SnapShot, &procEntry))
    return false;

do
{
    if (strcmp(procEntry.szExeFile, name) == 0)
        return true;
} while (Process32Next(SnapShot, &procEntry));

return false;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, otherwise we cant help you. How do you enumerate the running processes?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: `TCHAR` is a wide character type but not `char`; `strcmp` requires the arguments to be of type `const char *`

Comment: I'm a newbie to C++, could you please explain me how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert const WCHAR \* to const char \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637779/how-to-convert-const-wchar-to-const-char)

Comment: @PixelChemist, TCHAR isn't always a wide character type. See The answer by Ferruccio.

Comment: @George Correct, but obviously it is wide in case of OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the compiler message is clear:

in the `PROCESSENTRY32` struct, `szExeFile` is of type `tchar[]` while your input to the function is a `const char*`. You get the error because `strcmp` expects `char *` and not a wide character. You need to either

1. convert the `char` to a `tchar` string ( see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342976/how-to-convert-char-to-tchar?lq=1))
2. provide the input as a `tchar` string
3. compare with an appropriate function (see, e.g., in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529095/string-comparisons-how-can-you-compare-string-with-stdwstring-wrt-strcmp))

However, since you are using c++, why don't you use a `std::wstring` (and perform the conversion according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t))

Comment: How do i convert it to tchar? EDIT: I'm a newbie to C++, and I am still learning, I'm in hope someone teaches me how to do those conversions and fix this...

Comment: Uh oh, it talks about TCHAR and my problem is WCHAR. EDIT: Alright thanks then, i found out conversion and it worked.

Comment: Well, since you compile with unicode, `TCHAR` is an typedef to `wchar_t`, @realmaster42

Answer (score 3):

`TCHAR` is a wide character type if your programs is compiled for Unicode, a narrow character type otherwise. When you create a new project with VS2013, it will be set for Unicode, so `TCHAR` is most likely a wide character type. The simplest solution is to change the project settings to compile for non-Unicode instead.

1. Right-click on the project in the solution explorer window and select "Properties".
2. Select "Configuration Properties" and then "General".
3. Change the "Character Set" entry from "Unicode" to "Not Set" or "Multi-Byte".

When you compile now, `TCHAR` will be set to a narrow character type and your code should compile.

Comment: That is a nice answer, when writing my typedef comment, I thought about that, too, but dismissed that again. This is probably the easiest solution.